# Visual Studio Code is formatting a Flutter Dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My visual studio code is auto formatting when I save my dart file. How do I disable it?
Should I switch code editor?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to switch your editor. You can disable it by going to:
`File -> Preferences -> settings -> search dart formatter -> untick enable sdk formatter`